# SEEK_SET is #defined but must not be for the C++ binding of MPI. Include mpi.h before stdio.h

Tags: c++, compilation, mpi, intel

I'm running into the following error while compiling C++ application using Intel MPI:

```
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/include/mpicxx.h:95:2: error: #error "SEEK_SET is #defined but must not be for the C++ binding of MPI. Include mpi.h before stdio.h"
```

As per Intel's [solution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cluster-toolkit-for-linux-error-when-compiling-c-aps-using-intel-mpi-library-compilation-driver-mpiicpc), I've tried adding -DMPICH_IGNORE_CXX_SEEK and -DMPICH_SKIP_MPICXX during compiling time, i.e.

```
make CPPFLAGS="-DMPICH_IGNORE_CXX_SEEK -DMPICH_SKIP_MPICXX"
```

I'm not sure if I've done the above step correctly, because the error persisted even with the flag added. If I added it wrong, can someone please tell me the right way to add the options at compile time?

Edit: I added #include "mpi.h" and #include  at the top of communicator.h and make no longer shows communicator.h as part of the problem. However, for main.cu the problem persisted.

Full error is below:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874 -B/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/CMakeFiles /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/u/project/miao/y1lo/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/u/project/miao/y1lo/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/CMakeFiles 4
[  3%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//./sharp_generated_main.cu.o
cd /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir && /usr/bin/cmake -E make_directory /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//.
cd /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir && /usr/bin/cmake -D verbose:BOOL=1 -D build_configuration:STRING=release -D generated_file:STRING=/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//./sharp_generated_main.cu.o -D generated_cubin_file:STRING=/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//./sharp_generated_main.cu.o.cubin.txt -P /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//sharp_generated_main.cu.o.cmake
-- Removing /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//./sharp_generated_main.cu.o
/usr/bin/cmake -E remove /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//./sharp_generated_main.cu.o
-- Generating dependency file: /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//sharp_generated_main.cu.o.NVCC-depend
/u/local/cuda/5.5/bin/nvcc -M -D__CUDACC__ /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/src/main.cu -o /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//sharp_generated_main.cu.o.NVCC-depend -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -Dsharp_EXPORTS -Xcompiler ,\"-fPIC\",\"-O3\",\"-DNDEBUG\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DNVCC -I/u/local/cuda/5.5/include -I/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/cusplibrary-0.5.1 -I/u/local/cuda/5.5/include -I/usr/include -I/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/src -I/u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/include -I/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/include -I/u/home/y/y1lo/usr/local/hdf5/include -I/u/local/gcc/4.4.4/libs/fftw/3.2.2/include
In file included from /u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/include/mpi.h:1279,
                 from /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/src/main.cu:1:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/include/mpicxx.h:95:2: error: #error "SEEK_SET is #defined but must not be for the C++ binding of MPI. Include mpi.h before stdio.h"
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/include/mpicxx.h:99:2: error: #error "SEEK_CUR is #defined but must not be for the C++ binding of MPI. Include mpi.h before stdio.h"
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/include/mpicxx.h:104:2: error: #error "SEEK_END is #defined but must not be for the C++ binding of MPI. Include mpi.h before stdio.h"
CMake Error at sharp_generated_main.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
  Error generating
  /u/home/y/y1lo/project-miao/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build/src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir//./sharp_generated_main.cu.o


make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir/./sharp_generated_main.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/u/project/miao/y1lo/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build'
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/sharp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/u/project/miao/y1lo/camera/ptychography-sharp-dev-73eeb9f85874/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why not do what the error tells you to do: `#include "mpi.h"` then `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: I added those two #includes in main.cu and communicator.h but problem persists. Not sure where else I should add those includes.

Comment: I guess your preprocessor option is not doing what it is supposed to. It's hard to tell what is going on here because CMake obfuscates the build. Can you make it output verbose or invoke the compile line manually to test?

Comment: Let us look at your `communicator.h` header file. This sort of problem could occur if you don't have header guards and you `#include "communicator.h"` from within `main.cu` as well.

Comment: I've included the verbose make output. @NoseKnowsAll I added #include "mpi.h" and #include at the top of communicator.h and make no longer shows communicator.h as part of the problem, but it's not the case for main.cu.